# Getting full-screen resolution for FreeDOS on VirtualBOX

Tags: virtualbox, resolution, freedos

Following [these instructions](https://sourceforge.net/p/freedos/bugs/212/#0458), I have FreeDOS on VirtualBox installed. Now I want to get the fullscreen resolution. Usually, if it were a Linux or Windows guest I would use `menue>Devices>Insert Guest additions CD image...` and it would automatically start the installation or there would be instructions to install it manually or from a repository ...

However, I don't know how to do it for FreeDOS. I would appreciate if you could help me know how it should be done. Thanks for your support in advance.

**P.S.** I have also asked this question on [this Tweet](https://twitter.com/fsfarimani/status/1151220087476461570?s=20).

Answer (score 0):

Just started using it myself. I do not believe you can actually increase the resolution beyond what most programs are designed to use, especially for the console. I could be wrong, but for sure you are not going to get guest additions to work at all as that would require some sort of GUI environment.
However, you can use scaled mode and then fullscreen the window to get close to what you need.
[Image of Scaled Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9pMr.png)
[Image of Fullscreen Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mavdF.png)